# Laravel-Backpack I need upload images with 3 different thumbnails sizes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I need upload images with 3 different thumbnails sizes.

For example I upload image and now I get one thumbnail (48x48px), and I want to have 3 sizes: 100x100px, 300x300px, 600x600px.

How can I do this? Help me please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use package for that, this is best package you can use for that [Image intervention](http://image.intervention.io/)

You can use this code for resizing image after uploading.

```
// open an image file
$img = Image::make('public/original.jpg');

// now you are able to resize the instance
$img->resize(48,48);

// finally we save the image as a new file
$img->save('public/resized.jpg');
```

you can get installation setups for Laravel [here](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel)

Also please refer [documentation](http://image.intervention.io/use/basics) here.

Please refer this below code which I'm using to resize images.

```
// Upload image to Disk
$pic = $request->file('image');
$name =  $pic->getClientOriginalName();
$extension = $pic->getClientOriginalExtension();
$encrypted_name = md5(uniqid().time()).".".$extension; //Generate Unique name image
$pic->move("Path/to/Uploads",$encrypted_name);

// Read that image and resize that image.
$Image = "Path/to/Uploads".$image_name;
$img = \Image::make($Image)->resize(48,48);
$img->save('new_image_name');
```

Comment: Thank you! But I would like it makes thumbnail when I uploading an image, not after that. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, you can put some sort of logic there. Like save original image first into disk and then read that image to resize it.

Comment: But I can't find function which makes thumbnails. I checked almost all files in Vendor folder =(

Comment: But, you need to do it at your own, there is no code in Laravel inbuilt. Use the package I suggested you to resize image

Comment: @DimasYashchuk, Please check answer I've added code which I'm using to get thumbnail.

Comment: Ok. I will try. Thank you!